# compare line by line and report number of occurence

Tags: perl

how can I write a program in perl to compare line by line, report the line and its occurrence?

```
A    4481676    4483063
A    4481676    4483063
A    4481676    4483063
A    4481676    4483063
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
```

print this output

```
A    4481676    4483063   4
A    4483214    4483749   6
```

Comment: Don't even need to do any scripting... `sort data.txt | uniq -c` would work if you don't mind the count being at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Maryam Have provided a perl answer which can be used in a `.pl` file and doesn't use `Data::Dumper` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do this with a one-liner:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = "
A    4481676    4483063
A    4481676    4483063
A    4481676    4483063
A    4481676    4483063
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749
A    4483214    4483749";

my %seen;

while($input =~ /(.+)$/mg ){
    $seen{$1}++;
}

foreach my $key (keys %seen) {
    print "$key   $seen{$key}\n";
}
```

[Live demonstration](https://eval.in/47144) showing this gives desired output. If your input is a file, just use a filehandler and `while(<>)` in place of `while($input =~ /(.+)$/mg )`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file="file.txt";
open(DATA, "<" . $file);
my %seen;

while(<DATA>){
    $seen{$1}++;
}

foreach my $key (keys %seen) {
    print "$key   $seen{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As above but in perl

```
perl -n -e 'use Data::Dumper;$a{$_}++; END { print Dumper(\%a)}' file
```

Comment: thank you very much. But could please tell me how I can write it in a file.pl :) I want to learn it